# Convert JS object to JS array

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object like `{"1":true,"2":false,"3":true}`

I want to create a javascript array like `[1,3]` by taking the keys whose value is true.

How can I do that?

Comment: @VipinKumar, reopened even before posting your comment. And this not exact duplicate but OP could have used that answer to find his solution.

Comment: Totally agree with you. I too figured that out. Once i submitted the comment, duplicate was removed.

Comment: @VipinKumar, _Once i submitted the comment, duplicate was removed._ then you too could have removed the comment

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object#keys` with `array#filter` to return those key whose value is `true`.

```js
var obj = {"1":true,"2":false,"3":true};
var result = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k]).map(Number);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that Out of the box from ES5 using `Object.keys(yourobject)` and using the filter on top of it

```
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']
```

[Check it out here MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const o = {
    "1": true,
    "2": false,
    "3": true
};
const result = Object.entries(o).reduce((p, [k, v]) => v ? [...p, +k] : p, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the solution below. First you need to filter and then map to Numbers.

```js
var obj = {
  "1": true,
  "2": false,
  "3": true
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key]).map(key => Number(key))

console.log(keys);
```